# do not open pdf file when I got mail from laravel by attachData method

Tags: pdf, laravel-5.5, attachment

**Here is my code**

```
public function build(){
    return $this->view('senderMail.mail')->to('example@admin.com')->attachData("Just test for PDF", "Receipt.pdf",['mime' =>'application/pdf',]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Use dompdf laravel Package***

```
public function build(){
   $pdf = PDF::loadView('senderMail.mail');    
   $data = $pdf->output();

   return $this->view('senderMail.mail')
          ->to('example@admin.com')
          ->attachData($data, "Receipt.pdf",
         ['mime' =>'application/pdf',]);
}
```